# R Question: How do I add data to a column without replacing existing data?

Tags: r, replace, merge, datatable

So I have a basic table with empty column 1

**df**

```
ident col1
     1   NA
     2   NA
     3   NA
     4   NA
```

I have two other tables:

**df1**

```
  ident col1
     2  Yes
     3  Yes
```

**df2**

```
  ident col1
     1  No
     4  No
```

I am trying to add data from each df1 and df2 to the first table but when I add the second df2 data it replaces the current entires there that don't match with NA. So I wan't to add df1 data into col1 and then add df2 data into col1 by matching ident numbers and without replacing values in there.

Here is my code:

```
df$col1<- df1$col1[match(df$ident, df1$ident)]
```

and then I do the same for df2 but it replaces df1 data...

Any suggestions? Thanks

PS. My data is much more complicated than this, I just figured i would boil it down easier for ya.

Comment: Welp I guess my tables didn't format right. The three df are simply 2 columns, one with the ident numbers (1-4) and the col 1 is NA in the first df and then Yes and No in df 1 and df2 respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do the match the other way around

```
df$col1[match(df1$ident, df$ident)] <- df1$col1
df$col1[match(df2$ident, df$ident)] <- df2$col1


df
#    ident col1
# 1:     1   No
# 2:     2  Yes
# 3:     3  Yes
# 4:     4   No
```

You can also do this with data.table update joins

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, col1 := as.character(col1)]# may not be necessary (if data is already char)

df[df1, on = .(ident), col1 := i.col1]
df[df2, on = .(ident), col1 := i.col1]


df
#    ident col1
# 1:     1   No
# 2:     2  Yes
# 3:     3  Yes
# 4:     4   No
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks so much!